# Retrieving SAML token for a relying party trust using windows pass-through authentication

Tags: c#, token, saml, adfs

I'm attempting to determine a way for an application to retrieve a SAML token to access a relying party trust on behalf of the current context of the application (as a user).

The common recommendation is to retrieve a SAML token using WSTrustChannelFactory but with supplying a username and password. I would like to not do this so it is seamless to the user. I feel like ADFS should support SSO authentication (using passthrough windows auth) for this request. Is this possible?

Here is the typical recommended code that requires credentials:

```
public SecurityToken GetSamlToken()
{
        using (var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
        new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
        new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://serv/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed"))))
        {
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
        factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;                
        WSTrustChannel channel = null;                
        try
        {
            string KeyType;
            var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
                          {
                              RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
                              AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:xxxx/Service1/mex"),                         
                              KeyType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer,                                        
                          };

            channel = (WSTrustChannel)factory.CreateChannel();

            return channel.Issue(rst);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (channel != null)
            {
                channel.Abort();
            }

            factory.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by pass through auth? Are you referring to IWA? Or are you referring to AAD's PTA : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta Or are you using an only on-prem ADFS server? If you're referring to AAD PTA, there is a concept of seamless sso : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-how-it-works

Comment: I believe IWA is the route I'm trying to go. I need to authenticate the user from my application to ADFS and then retrieve a SAML token for a relying party.

Comment: So can you please clarify what you mean by Pass through auth? Because all references of Pass Through Auth refer to the connection between AAD and on-prem ADFS. Are you referring to something else?

Comment: I think that is part of the confusion. I believe I'm trying to use IWA on-prem. Do you know of an example or solution to the problem I'm trying to solve? This seems like something that should be possible using on-prem ADFS. Thank you!

Comment: It's not possible for me to provide the exact example that you need as we need a FULL understanding of your environment. If you have an Hybrid Identity setup, then it will require a different solution than an on-prem identity setup. My suggestion is to take a look at Vittorio's blogs for ADFS solutions : http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/?s=sso+adfs and 
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/21/openid-connect-web-sign-on-with-adfs-in-windows-server-2016-tp3/

Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using on-prem AD FS, you can still get tokens using Integrated Windows Authentication (SPNEGO) using the `windowstransport` endpoint of ADFS on .Net 7 and higher:

```
var binding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, new EndpointAddress(
    "https://adfs.example.com/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport"));
var req = new WsTrustRequest(WsTrustActions.Trust13.Issue)
{
    AppliesTo = new AppliesTo(new EndpointReference("urn:example:rp:identity")),
    KeyType = WsTrustKeyTypes.Trust13.Bearer,
    WsTrustVersion = WsTrustVersion.Trust13,
};
var stschannel = factory.CreateTrustChannel();
var token = (GenericXmlSecurityToken)await stschannel.IssueAsync(req);
Console.WriteLine(token.TokenXml.OuterXml);
```

You will need to add references to:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml" Version="7.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

`windowsmixed`/`TransportWithMessageCredential`, on the other hand, is not supported on netcore.